# How to preserve html when parsing xml using Jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

Suppose I have the following XML structure:

```
<root>
 <item>
  <item1>some text is <b>here</b></item1>
  <item2>more text is here</item2>
 </item>
</root>
```

I can parse the xml using something like:

```
$(responseXML).find('item').each(function(){
             var first_text = $(this).find('item1').text();
             var second_text = $(this).find('item2').text();
}
```

But the html is not preserved when using .text(). html() is not available for xml in jquery.

Any ideas on how to keep the inner html when parsing the xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nest the sections you don't want interpreted as xml within CDATA sections
e.g.

```
<root>
 <item>
  <item1><![CDATA[some text is <b>here</b>]]></item1>
  <item2><![CDATA[more text is here]]></item2>
 </item>
</root>
```

EDIT: Note, if using .text() doesn't work, try the following:

Quoting from: http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/2425

> I've just re-encountered this. For the curious my workaround is instead of using .text() to use this plugin I created (simply replace .text() with .getCDATA():

```
jQuery.fn.getCDATA = function() {
if($.browser.msie)
    return this[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    // Other browsers do this
return this[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
 };
```

> It ain't pretty, but in my case did the job.

Comment: So if the html is not enclosed in CDATA, there is no way around it right?

Comment: correct. unless you want to try parsing the text which would get very messy, and I would advise against if you can avoid it

Answer (score 3):

`Text()` will give you the text information of the node.
However if you use:

```
var first_text = $(this).find('item1').html();
var second_text = $(this).find('item2').html();
```

you will get the HTML tags too.

Comment: Thanks David, Im new to adding comments to Stack, i didn't know to add code like that.